# Apache Rewrite issue with url with more than 1 slash

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

The problem is basically this:

I have an url: `site.com?go=1&do=2&action3&id=4`

if i use the rewrite method like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?go=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?go=$1&do=$2
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?go=$1&do=$2&action=$3
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?go=$1&do=$2&action=$3&id=$4
```

It works only with the first Slash. for example:

`site.com/go` -> this works but this `site.com/go/do` breaks the whole page, it can't find the css, imgs, nothing! How can i solve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `<base>` tag into your head and put your domain name into href

```
<head>
<base href="http://www.sample.com/">
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks! that solved my problem, i have to wait 7 minutes to accept your answer =S

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the structure of your URLs, you may want to make sure that you're URL escaping backreferences.  Check out https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html